# Регулярные выражения + vk

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Столкнулся с задачей,в которой нужно использовать регулярные выражения.

```
if (preg_match('/[ Ник: ][a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}$\n Сервер: \d/',$message,$matches)) {
    $vk->SendMessage($peer_id,"n" . $matches[0] . "s" . $matches[1]);
  }
```

Получаемое сообщение от api($message) - `&#128196; Ник: catty\n&#128196; Сервер: 5",`
Почему не срабатывает? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а что вы ожидаете увидеть в `matches[0]` и `[1]` ?

Comment: информацию полученную с помощью регулярок. 
matches[0] = catty
matches[1] = 5

Comment: в matches попадают группы захвата, которые в регулярках обозначаются скобками `()`. В вашей регулярке нет ни одной такой группы. Дополнительно - в matches[0] - всегда находится полная строка соответствия, а непосредственные группы с 1.

Comment: что-то такое должно быть в итоге https://regex101.com/r/Exkml0/1

Comment: Спасибо,вы безумно мне помогли,все работает =)